# Wordcloud in R not displaying anything

Tags: r, word-cloud

I have an object (wordc) in R that looks like this

```
> wordc
tw.text
           aint     booking       coast         coz     getting       hello 
  6           1           1           1           1           1           1 
message      modern moderncoast       mpesa      online     payment     working 
  1           1           1           1           1           1           1
```

I'm trying to build the cloud as follows:

```
wordsc <- names(wordc)
freqc <- as.vector(wordc)
wordcloud(wordsc, freqc)
```

But it doesn't produce anything.

If I try the following (as per documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.pdf)) then it works

```
wordcloud(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), seq(1, 1000, len = 62))
```

The type of values I'm feeding wordcloud seem to be the same as you can see below:

```
> typeof(wordsc)
[1] "character"
> typeof(freqc)
[1] "double"
> typeof(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9))
[1] "character"
> typeof(seq(1, 1000, len = 62))
[1] "double"
```

Can someone give me a hint as to why the wordcloud I'm trying to build is now working

Thanks

Comment: My guess: `wordcloud(wordsc, freqc)` is actually `wordcloud(wordsc, freqc, min.freq=3)` by default. The only word that has a frequency greater 2 is an empty string. So... lower `min.freq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by lukeA in the comments, adjust the argument `min.freq`.

A reproducible example:

```
w <- c(foo=1,bar=1,baz=5)
```

Only printing words above 1 count (when there is at least one):

```
wordcloud::wordcloud(names(w), w)
```

[image]

Plot all:

```
wordcloud::wordcloud(names(w), w, min.freq = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I understand. Thanks